# How test the send_data method in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How can I test the `send_data` method in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I read his question I took it to mean, how does he make sure that send_data sent the string/whatever he asked it to.  Not so much to test it's sending but to ensure for his peace of mind that the method he's sent it wasn't blank.  mocking, as you've done, doesn't really get him that result.

Perhaps you can ensure that your string isn't blank, or something like that.  This way you aren't testing send_data, but that whatever send_data gets is how you want it to look.

In my case (what brought me to this question) would be

```
#just use this to make sure it looks like you want it to while you are writing your
#tests. I remove it after. make sure it's an instance variable @csv_string in my case.
puts assigns(:csv_string) 

refute_nil assigns(:csv_string) #does the actual work. delete the puts line when done.
```

Some fancier people use ruby debugger and sh!t... your mileage will vary.

Comment: Controller test is about mocks. If you need something "real", make an integration test. The solution below is actually the "rspec way" if you wil.

Comment: Controller test is about mocks? odd statement and worse, a down vote. When you mock that, you aren't testing anything but the fact that send_data got called and it goes on to do it's work.  In my example, as the OP said, we are testing that send_data is actually doing it's job. one test for piece of mind.

Comment: Use a integration test for that. unit tests are not place for testing send_data works.

Comment: Well if you are getting pedantic, I'm actually suggesting that this test would be a functional test, if you are using Rails parlance, but regardless of the actual place the test is located, again, the answer stands.

Answer (score 29):

First of all look at the source of the `send_data` method http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/DataStreaming.html#method-i-send_data

According to that, `send_data` simply put everything to `render :text => '...'` with additional options.

I think you can do it in this way:

```
response.body.should eql data
response.header['Content-Type'].should eql 'image/png'
```

Answer (score 9):

You shouldn't need to test the behaviour of `send_data` itself, mainly because that's covered by Rails' own tests. Also, it will make your tests run slowly (eventually). What you should do (from my perspective) is to stub the send_data method, something like:

`controller.expects(:send_data).with("foo").returns(:success)`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I do not recommend this. Mocking code you don't own is generally not a good idea. If the API for `send_data` changes (say, with a Rails upgrade), you won't know that your code is broken.

Comment: @XavierShay that is highly debatable. Mocking and stubbing code that you don't own is often considered the Only Good Way to have real unit tests. However, the "upstream may change" is something you will want to catch in tests. But not in unit-tests. You should have integration tests for that. (This, is, just as your point, just an opinion, there are many)

Comment: "Mocking and stubbing code that you don't own is often considered the Only Good Way to have real unit tests." reference? I'd like to read more about this working well (long term) for people. To support my own assertion above: http://www.jmock.org/oopsla2004.pdf and the top handful of results on https://www.google.com/?#safe=active&q=only+mock+types+you+own

Comment: (fwiw I have some experiments on alternative ways of doing controllers that is more classically unit tested: https://github.com/xaviershay/poniard )

Answer (score 5):

You can test it indirectly by checking the value of `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

```
expect(controller.headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"]).to eq("binary")
```

or

```
controller.headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"].should eq("binary")
```

Comment: controller is undefined

Answer (score 1):

For a `minitest` version answer:

```
assert_equal("application/json", response.header["Content-Type"])
assert_equal(expected_response, response.body)
```